# how to charge stripe payment in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, stripe-payments

i'm developing `hybrid` app using `ionic`. i want to pay with stripe in my app but Stripe’s ionic native plugin doesn’t seem to have charging functionality (it’s only for creating a token and validating card info, and nothing else), and I can’t find any tutorial showing how to charge a card & stuff.

I’ve searched google and all I’ve seen are plugins & templates for full integration, all for sale.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I’m at a stand still at the moment.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges the charge has to happen server-side. If you need code to use end-to-end, the best solution would be to hire a developer to build this for you